# Format Time field in Crystal Report formula

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, sql-server-2012

Here is the deal, i have an SQL database with a Time(7) field, when i make the connection to CR in VS project the CR detects my Time database column as String... or so it makes me believe. i can import all my data from the database but when i try to format the filed in the report using CR formula i get the ***"to many arguments have been given to this function"***

I've read a lot and tied many formulas and still cant correct this issue, my current formula code (as simple as it seems) is:

> totext ({Checkin_CheckoutT.Checkin_time}, "hh:mm")

I've tried another code that seems to be on the right track:

> Totext(CTime({Checkin_CheckoutT.Checkin_time}), "hh:mm")

but with this one i get the ***"bad time format string "*** when i refresh my report.
I've been looking at this the whole day and still no solution...Please Help!

Current software:
SQL managger 2012,
VS 2012,
Sap CR 13.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time(7) is just a very precise time field, but Crystal (or at least the version being used) was built before Time(7) existed, so it doesn't know what to do with it.  The result is a string of the time in `hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` format.  If all you need is the hours and minutes in a string, then use `Left({Checkin_CheckoutT.Checkin_time}, 5)` to pull out the first 5 characters (which would be the `hh:mm` part).

You can also flip it back to Crystal time afterwards if that is what is needed: `CTime(Left({Checkin_CheckoutT.Checkin_time}, 5))`

Comment: This was the Correct Answer, thanks a lot, i didn't know the Time type was that new.

Answer (score 1):

If you Crystal is reading it as a string field and you don't wanna mess with SQL code to convert it this should work. Im pretty sure I remember that SQL time(7) field is in hh:mm:ss.ms

`time(tonumber(split({yourtime7string},":")[1]),tonumber(split({yourtime7string},":")[2]),0)`

from there right click, format field and tell Crystal how you want it to look.

if you must format it in the formula

```
totext(time(tonumber(split({yourtime7string},":")[1]),tonumber(split({yourtime7string},":")[2]),0),"HH:mm")
```

Comment: this is also correct but a bit longer, the other option was a bit more appealing. Thank you for your time :)